# print lines between x and y from the log using Perl

Tags: perl, unix, xml-parsing

I have log file and that contain some xml messages like...

```
<fixsim xyz='tststtsts'>
  <name test="test1">
    <time t=234>
    </time>
  </name>
</fixsim>


here some normal log text
whoiwoei
blsdbndsnb

<fixsim xyz='tssts'
  <name test="test2"
<time t=234>
    </time>
  </name>
</fixsim>
```

and so on....

From the above log file i want to grab the xml message (`from <Fixsim> to </fixsim>`) with some condition. For example

i want xml message having test= test2. so as output i should get

```
<fixsim xyz='tssts'
  <name test="test2"
<time t=234>
    </time>
  </name>
</fixsim>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will get the XML docs:

```
process($_) for $log =~ m{<fixsim.*?</fixsim>}sg;
```

and so would

```
my $xml;
while (<$log_fh>) {
   if ( my $count = m{<fixsim} .. m{</fixsim>} ) {
      $xml .= $_;

      if ($count =~ /E0\z/) {
          process($xml);
          $xml = undef;
      }
   }

   process($xml) if defined($xml);
}
```

Once you got the XML, you can extract the field you need using your favorite XML parser.

Comment: You means $log is file handle? Because need to work with log file.

Comment: is it possible by using sed -n to get this message with certain condition?

Comment: No, not a file handle. The log file contents.

Comment: log file is too huge so not possible to put whole in variable. And also this message is not in single line, that is in multiple line.

Comment: So accumulate lines in a buffer. Updated.

Comment: @ ikegami Thanks, perfect one. But could you please explain both IF statement?

Comment: The first uses the flip-flop operator, documented in perlop. It's a state machine that identifies the lines you want. The second checks if the value in `$count` ends with `E0`.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to filter that message during regular expression instead of using XML parser, because log file is huge and lot of xml messages are in there.So it would be better if there is way of buffer only filtered message.

Comment: You can't read the file line by line and make decisions based on lines you haven't read yet. But you could write your own "parser" using regular expressions after you identified the XML (i.e. in `process`.)